# Subsonic 3 getpaged filter question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subsonic3

I am sure this is a stupid question, but how would I get a pagedlist of filtered items?

Here is how I ended up doing it:

```
PagedList<Company> company = Company.GetPaged(1, 10);

var list = Company.Find(x => x.CompanyName.ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower()));
company .Clear();

foreach (var x in list)
    company .Add(x);

return View(company );
```

In other words I want to do a find on the table, and return a paged list of the results.

Thanks!

Comment: How about posting your own answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is a fantastic example of this in NerdDinner.

If you have trouble finding it then let me know and I'll post the code for ya.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at NerdDinner and found what you are talking about.  I had trouble with it erroring out saying there was no aggregate or group by.  I ended up solving it a little differently.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's fairly easy to get the paged list and you said the answer in your question

> In other words I want to do a find on
>   the table, and return a paged list of
>   the results.

- Create your LINQ query (*do a find on the table*)
- New up a SubSonic.Schema.PagedList(of T)  (*return a paged list*)

For example:

```
var list = Company.Find(x => x.CompanyName.ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower()));
var paged = new SubSonic.Schema.PagedList<Company>(list,1,10)
```